# Appengine datastore concurrent commits

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am trying to understand what happens during race conditions on the Google AppEngine datastore. I have been using Objectify, so I'll use that notation here.

```
@Cached
public class Car {
  @Id
  public Long id;
  @Unindexed
  public String owner = "C";
}
```

Now consider I have two runnables that try to modify the `owner` of a particular car simultaneously.

```
Car myCar = ofy.get(Car.class, 10);
myCar.owner = "A";  // Other runnable uses "B"
ofy.put(myCar);
System.out.println(ofy.get(Car.class, 10).owner);
```

I presume in this case its undetermined whether Car(10) will be "owned" by "A" or "B" but no errors will be reported. It would not be clear to the "loser" until the writes were persisted into the datastore. What would the result of the printlns be?

If I had used transactions, would one of the runnables (the "loser") have raised an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Both entities use the same ID (10) so one `put()` will overwrite the other. It's only the question which does it first.
2. The second transaction to `put()` would get the exception.

**Edit:**

You might get different exceptions during transaction, not all of them mean that change was not (or will not be) commited. You should actually inspect the transaction and rollback if appropriate. See first example: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions.html

Comment: Just to be clear, the second transaction would get the exception and thus not overwrite?

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. A bit tricky to test so the confirmation is helpful!

Comment: Actually, the second transaction will get a concurrent modification exception, retry, and succeed the second time, overwriting the value. You need to add logic to avoid that if that's your desired effect.

Comment: You got me agai on a incomplete answer. Thx ;)